# How to handle Oracle Database where table names has lower case names with Symfony5 / Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I wanted to start a mapping:import with doctrine from an existing Oracle Database. But alle table names and column names in the database are written in small letters. So while doing an mapping:import doctrine writes all Entities Symfony 5/Doctrine 2 wanted to write Entities like this but

instead of Users.php (Entity) doctrine mapper wanted to write "users".php but this gives an error. Also all table names and column names which are written in small letters will be transform into quoted names like "column1".

Is there a way to handle lower case names in Oracle Databases with Symfony5/Doctrine 2? And how?

Thank you

Comment: I don't have an Oracle database to test against but I think you may have something else going on.  All of the table and columns in my mysql databases are also lower case and things work just fine.  Doctrine has naming strategies which take care of this sort of thing.  Are you using some kind of legacy project which has been updated to Symfony 5?  Might try with a fresh project making no changes to the out of the box setup.

Comment: @Cerad - mysql handles these things much differently than oracle, so no parallels can be drawn.

Comment: In oracle, object names are, by default, created (in the data dictionary) with upper-case names and handled as case IN-sensitive.  However, if they are _created_ with the name _in double-quotes_, then they are created (in the data dictionary) exactly as specified, and are treated as _case sensitive_.  That means all references will also have to be in double quotes and exactly with the case as created.  For this reason, it is bad practice to be creating case-sensitive names in the first place.

Comment: I do not create a Oracle database or a database table. There is already a database where table names and column names all lower case!! And with this I've got tremendous problems with mapping import  with Doctrine!